# Remove fields if their key is longer than x chars in Logstash?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, logstash-filter

I have a `logstash` pipeline for the most part, parses data sufficiently into JSON to go to `elasticsearch`; however... Sometimes it does not parse fields very well, and finds keys and values which are very weird, most of the time, these keys are very long, such as: `aaaakgaaaaiaaaaaaaaaabiofy1mb...`.

I was hoping to be able to remove these fields based on how long the key is in the `kv`. Say any field over 30 chars is removed. Although I may improve the `logstash` parsing in the futurethat these problems won't persist, for now I'd like to have something such as this as a last stitched sanity check.

Answer (score 0):

Try this filter whith 2 steps :

1. prefix kv field to be able to identify them (optional here)
2. loop on this prefixed field to apply the condition (here the limit is 30 prefix included)

   ```
       filter {
         kv { 
           #Step 1
           #prefix=>"kv_"
         }
         ruby {
           code => "
             hash = event.to_hash
             hash.each do |key, value|
             # Step 2
             #if(key.to_s.start_with?('kv_'))
               if(key.size>30)
                 event.cancel
               end
             #end
             end
            "
          }
        }
   ```

Comment: What purpose does prefixing keys serve?

Comment: Because without, the loop in ruby, turn on every field, not only fields provided by kv filter. I understand that point could create wrong field name in elasticsearsh, so you can remove this prefix in ruby to have the exact field name. Anyway if the condition is the size (more the 30-, you could remove this prefix in the kv filter, and in the ruby (first if).